# XSLT Keep adding variable in a loop

Tags: xslt

I am looking for an idea on how to be able to add variable in for-each loop.

```
<group>
   <spare bitCnt="5"/>
   <integer name="A" bitCnt="11"/>
   <spare bitCnt="15"/>
   <integer name="B" bitCnt="1"/>
</group>
```

Expected header file output:

```
UINT16 A: 11;
UINT16 spare: 5;
UINT16 B: 1;
UINT16 spare 15;
```

I need to keep adding the bitCnt of variables in the 'group' and if the variable falls on the word boundary of 2 bytes, I need to swap the order of the elements.

My question is "how can I keep track of the bitCnt as I run the elements in the for-each loop?"
I would something like totalBitCnt in the xslt and in for-each loop, keep adding the totalBitCnt to determine if "totalBitCnt mod 16" is zero.
So, it would increment like 5, 18(5+13), 23(15+18), 24(23+1) as it runs the loop.
Any general approach is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: "*how can I keep track of the bitCnt as I run the elements in the for-each loop?*" That's not possible, because `xsl:for-each` is not a loop. Use a recursive template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I grok you particular context so I'll answer in general terms.

Accumulating in a for loop is an iterative approach and XSLT (I guess you're using 1.0) is very limited in that matter. I think your best bet is to set up something recursive.

Named templates could be defined and invoked instead of the for-each loop. You'd define it with parameters such as: a list of element to process and the accumulator.

```
<xsl:template name="accumulator-template">
  <xsl:param name="elements"/>
  <xsl:param name="accumulator"/>

  <!-- do stuff to the first element -->

  <xsl:variable name="elements-left" select="$elements[???]"/> <!-- Exclude element that was processed -->

  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$elements-left">
      <!-- LOOPING -->
      <xsl:call-template name="accumulator-template">
        <xsl:with-param name="elements" select="$elements-left"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="accumulator" select="$accumulator + number(@stuff)"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <!-- END OF LOOP -->
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Then you'd invoke it instead of writing an inline for-each loop:

```
<xsl:call-template name="accumulator-template">
  <xsl:with-param name="elements" select="group"/>
  <xsl:with-param name="elements" select="0"/> <!-- or any other starting value -->
</xsl:call-template>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It greatly helped me to find a solution using recursion.